# Using Lightbox with Awkward Showcase

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, lightbox

I'm having problems using [Lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox/) with [Awkward Showcase](http://www.awkwardgroup.com/sandbox/awkward-showcase-a-jquery-plugin/). I can open the images separately, but they should be grouped. Apparently, Awkward Showcase creates the elements on demand and events are lost for unloaded elements. It seems that the `.live` function should work, something like:

```
$(".showcase-content a").live('click', function() {
  $.fancybox({
    'autoDimensions': false,
    'width': 'auto',
    'height': 'auto',
    'href': $(this).attr('href')
  });
  return false;
});
```

or

```
$(".awkward a").live("click", function() {
  $.fancybox({
    'href': 'bigimage.jpg'
  });
});
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Where exactly should I apply this function? What data do I change? For now, I had to put the Lightbox links inside each slide call in the HTML, but that is a very poor solution.

Answer (score 0):

here I wrote an example code for you so you could take a look how fancybox works:
http://jsfiddle.net/tt1a5hyh/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".showcase-content a").fancybox();
});
```

The main idea in JQuery is not to handle with click event here but just set the 'fancybox' function on the element you need:

```
$(".showcase-content a").fancybox();
```

I wrapped it into 'document ready' in order to make sure that images are loaded and then the script would start working.

I hope my example will help you in figuring out how these kind of lightboxes work.

Comment: small update: there's an error in naming planes I used in pictures for example. This update fixes the wrong naming :0) http://jsfiddle.net/tt1a5hyh/1/

Comment: Eugene, I try: $(document).ready(function(){ $(".slideshowgaleria-content a").Lightbox(); }); But unsuccessfully.

Comment: Anyone? Please help me!

Comment: John, in your first example you use fancybox(). In my example I'm using fancybox() that works. Do you understand how it works?

Comment: because currently you are asking about another function: Lightbox() - feel the difference with fancybox() !!! This is another library, another CSS and parameters. If you include lighbox library correctly - everything should be working.